# Insert Figure in the same space

Tags: graphics

Currently, I am writing my resume and I write

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/asus_user/Pictures/} }
\begin{document}

\vspace*{-6cm}

\flushright
\begin{frame}{}
    \includegraphics[width=2.75cm, height=4cm]{head}
\end{frame}

\begin{center}
    WANG \\
    Tel.(Mobile) : 12345 \\
    Tel. (Home) : 12345 \\
    Email : alanwang@my
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I want to insert my photo on the right hand side of these four lines.

But what i desire does not happen. How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Please provide a compilable document, not just fragments. I doubt that you actually used `$$$` in your code. `\begin{frame}` looks like `beamer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a nested `tabular` approach. Depending on the real size of the photo there's some adaption to be done, of course, as well as left/right alignment (e.g. dropping the `center` environment) and the geometry of the page, e.g. the top margin.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{letter}

\usepackage{graphicx}

%\graphicspath{ {C:/Users/asus_user/Pictures/} }
\begin{document}

%\vspace*{-6cm}


\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{WANG} \tabularnewline
    Tel.(Mobile): &12345 \tabularnewline
    Tel. (Home): & 12345 \tabularnewline
    Email: & alanwang@my \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[b]{r}
\includegraphics[width=2.75cm, height=4cm]{beeduck}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{lr}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{WANG} \tabularnewline
    Tel.(Mobile): &12345 \tabularnewline
    Tel. (Home): & 12345 \tabularnewline
    Email: & alanwang@my \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}{r}
\includegraphics[width=2.75cm, height=4cm]{beeduck}
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the column environment and create appropriate columns for the desired effect. Here is the code I used to generate the picture

`\begin{columns}[T]
\column{0.43\linewidth}\begin{block}{Assumption}
\begin{itemize}
\item Text.
\item Text.
\item Text.
\item Text.
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\column{0.5\linewidth}
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{../01_pic/architecture.pdf}
\end{figure} 
\end{columns}`

[image]

Comment: Apparently you misinterpreted `frame` as I've done as coming from `beamer` class.